# Why does spacy return vectors for words like 'zz' ? Should they not be zero vectors

Tags: spacy

nlp.('zz').vector.sum is -10.

nlp('asc').vector.sum is -9.677

Shouldn't these words be out of vocabulary and have zero vectors ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model you're using, the training corpus may contain a lot of abbreviations, informal words (such as the ones in your example), typos and even words of external languages. These are still treated as lexemes and are assigned vectors.

Answer (score -1):

https://spacy.io/usage/models

Spacy's default English model doesn't include vectors, so it tries to deduce them from your text. If you use the larger models, they include vectors.

v This will not have effective vectors

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

^ This will have the vectors you're looking for (I believe)